# Getting customer name based on lowest order from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner learning SQL. I have 2 tables. Trying to get the customer first and last name with least transaction amount - only that 1 row. Been trying different code all day but getting nowhere.

Table 1: **Orders**

```
Customer_Id  TxnDate     Amount
-------------------------------
4001         21-Aug-18   245.99
4002         30-Jan-18    49.99
4003         15-Apr-17   204.87
4001         18-Dec-18   130.88
4004         15-May-17   198.33
4006          4-Feb-17   783.65
```

Table 2: **Customers**

```
Customer_Id  AcctOpenDate  CustomerFirstName  CustomerLastName
--------------------------------------------------------------
4001          7-Jan-16     John               Doe
4002         15-Apr-15     Ashley             Smith
4003         14-May-14     Carter             Jones
4004         17-Sep-16     Ika                Gaut
4005         18-Aug-14     Gray               Show
4006         25-Oct-15     Kathia             Kim
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    C.CustomerFirstName, C.CustomerLastName, O.Amount 
FROM 
    Customers C 
WHERE 
    Amount = (SELECT MIN(Amount) FROM Orders) Leasttxnamt 
INNER JOIN 
    Customers C ON O.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id;
```

Current error produced:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Leasttxnamt'

Comment: Please tag appropriate database name and your expected output with sample data.

Comment: Thank you.  That is much better!  Sample data should be:  CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Leasttxnamt.  Only one row which should be the lowest transaction amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

returns first and last name of customers with lowest transaction amount

```
select CustomerFirstName,CustomerLastName
from Customer
where   Customer_Id in (
SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Id
from  Orders
where Amount=(select min(Amount) from orders))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for customer wise MIN amount from the Order table. If this is correct, you can use the following script for your purpose-

> This is workable in most of the databases.

```
SELECT C.CustomerFirstName, C.CustomerLastName, MIN(Amount) min_amount
FROM Customers C 
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id
GROUP BY C.CustomerFirstName, C.CustomerLastNam
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query :

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerFirstName ,Customers.CustomerLastName
FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Customers.Customer_Id = Orders.Customer_Id
AND Orders.Amount=(
          SELECT min(Amount) FROM Orders
          WHERE Customers.Customer_Id = Orders.Customer_Id 
        )
```